# Saving time to table on button click mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, time

I am currently developing an internal website and wish to include a feature for my co-workers to clock-in and clock-out; I wish to have a model that generates a table that lists the date and the clock-in and out times at the days start, lunch start, lunch end and end of the day.

I do not know of a way to save these times to the table using a button, as I do not wish for people to be able to edit, forge (through typing in an earlier time) or delete the times.

If anyone is able to suggest a way to help me resolve this puzzle I'd be very grateful!

Comment: The logic seems pretty straightforward to me. You have a button, on button click the site records the current datetime to a table. Doesn't seem difficult. What part are you actually stuck on? Have you started attempting an implementation? Because I'm not clear what you're actually asking, and so it sounds like you just want us to write all the logic for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you've actually just given me the prompt i needed to make this work! I'd forgotten about the value datetime and as a result had confused myself over this straightforward logic, my apologies for wasting your time - I'm relatively new to coding as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a very simple level you could have a controller with a simple methods which passes the current DateTime and Username to a method which works out if they are currently punched in (in which case it would punch them out) or punched out (in which case it would punch them in):

```
[Post]
public ActionResult Process()
{
  // Get the current Time. This will be server time. 
  var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
  var user = User.Identity.Name;

  myDatabaseService.SaveUserActivity(user, currentTime);

  return View();
}
```

I'm unsure how you're managing users etc but by working out the user server side it prevents user A clocking in/out for user B.

Comment: Thanks for your help this is exactly what I needed:)

Answer (score -1):

You should just give them a button to say clock in - and when they click it, save the system time to the database. That way they have no way of entering a wrong time.

Comment: You basically just restated the requirements.

Comment: No, I meant dont give them the ability to enter the time, but only provide the button. And use code (System.DateTime.Now) to save the time tot he database.

Comment: I know what you mean, but you've just restated the requirements. You haven't really provided a solution here. This can be avoided by waiting until the question is clear before answering. You do not have to answer every question that comes in front of you.

Comment: For that matter, I see that you have just restated the question in your comment as well. I dont get it.. A genuine attempt to help this person and you mark it as 'not useful'??? and no I dont try and answer every question in front of me, just happened to think this was straightforward.

Comment: Thanks both for your input; SGK prompting me with system.Datetime.now was very helpful, apologies for the lack of clarity over my question!

Comment: A comment is not the same thing as an answer. My comment's purpose was to seek clarification because it wasn't clear where Evar was actually stuck.

Comment: For that matter you just restated the requirements in your comment as well. I dont get it... A genuine attempt to help this person, and you mark it as 'not useful'???

Comment: I cannot comment because I dont have the points to do so. If thats what you were implying that you could have politely done so.. What is happening to stackoverflow??? And you are very welcome Evar!

Comment: Whether it's a genuine attempt to help or not is irrelevant. It's not based on participation. The question wasn't clear, you rushed to answer before the question was clear. Therefore, not useful. If you need clarification on a question, then leave a comment. If you don't have the reputation to comment, then come back later when you do.

Comment: Obviously the person who asked the question found my answer useful, so I'm good..